# MATLAB vs Simulink in digital image processing?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there anything I can do with code in MATLAB for digital image processing that I can't do with Simulink's digital image processing toolbox or vice versa?

What difference is there between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the code level, there's not much difference between MATLAB and Simulink. Simulink provides an environment for constructing programs at a higher level of abstraction than text; the relationships that hold between code blocks is represented as arrows that pass between flowchart objects. You can then visualize the system as it operates at runtime, as data objects are passed visibly between the flowchart blocks. Simulink also lets you alter a part of the program in real time, so that you can see the effects of the local change without having to stop everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Given how much image processing work is done in block-level dataflow languages such as [LabVIEW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabVIEW), I would recommend starting with Simulink. Most industrial or creative image processing (like Apple's [Shake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shake_%28software%29)) is done via a node-based interface. That's not to say that you couldn't use MATLAB code as well; it's just a bit more obtuse ([this is a good example of a powerful library that was made with MATLAB code](https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD)).